# Can't sum calculations with AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm doing system to buy promotion for ads, so each ad can have Stars and Days. I need to count sum of points for each Ad, then summ all points needed for all ads. Problem is that Total is always zero and I get no error. Why?

```
<div x-data="{ total: 0 }">
  <div class="flex" x-data="{ days: 1, stars: 1 }">
    <select x-model="days" @change="updateTotal()">
      <option value="1">1 day</option>
      <option value="2">2 days</option>
      <option value="3">3 days</option>
    </select>

    <select x-model="stars" @change="updateTotal()">
      <option value="1">1 star</option>
      <option value="2">2 stars</option>
      <option value="3">3 stars</option>
    </select>

    <div x-text="days * stars" id="sum"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex" x-data="{ days: 1, stars: 1 }">
    <select x-model="days" @change="updateTotal()">
      <option value="1">1 day</option>
      <option value="2">2 days</option>
      <option value="3">3 days</option>
    </select>

    <select x-model="stars" @change="updateTotal()">
      <option value="1">1 star</option>
      <option value="2">2 stars</option>
      <option value="3">3 stars</option>
    </select>

    <div x-text="days * stars" id="sum"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex" x-data="{ days: 1, stars: 1 }">
    <select x-model="days" @change="updateTotal()">
      <option value="1">1 day</option>
      <option value="2">2 days</option>
      <option value="3">3 days</option>
    </select>

    <select x-model="stars" @change="updateTotal()">
      <option value="1">1 star</option>
      <option value="2">2 stars</option>
      <option value="3">3 stars</option>
    </select>

    <div x-text="days * stars" id="sum"></div>
  </div>

  <div x-text="'Total: ' + total"></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      updateTotal();
    });

    function updateTotal() {
      var total = 0;
      $('#sum').each(function() {
        var value = parseInt($(this).text());
        if (!isNaN(value)) {
          total += value;
        }
      });
      Alpine.store('total', total);
    }

    Alpine.data('example', () => ({
      total: Alpine.store('total'),

      mounted() {
        this.$watch('$refs.sum', () => {
          updateTotal();
          this.total = Alpine.store('total');
        });
      },
    }));
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is completely unnecessary here, you should use Alpine.js' data model inside the component. A single reduction function call is enough to get the total points.

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<div x-data="{ promos: {
                  promo1: {days: 1, stars: 1},
                  promo2: {days: 1, stars: 1},
                  promo3: {days: 1, stars: 1},
              },

              get total() {
                return Object.values(this.promos).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.days*cur.stars, 0)
              }
  }">
  <div class="flex">
    <select x-model.number="promos.promo1.days">
      <option value="1">1 day</option>
      <option value="2">2 days</option>
      <option value="3">3 days</option>
    </select>

    <select x-model.number="promos.promo1.stars">
      <option value="1">1 star</option>
      <option value="2">2 stars</option>
      <option value="3">3 stars</option>
    </select>

    <div class="sum" x-text="promos.promo1.days * promos.promo1.stars"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <select x-model.number="promos.promo2.days">
      <option value="1">1 day</option>
      <option value="2">2 days</option>
      <option value="3">3 days</option>
    </select>

    <select x-model.number="promos.promo2.stars">
      <option value="1">1 star</option>
      <option value="2">2 stars</option>
      <option value="3">3 stars</option>
    </select>

    <div class="sum" x-text="promos.promo2.days * promos.promo2.stars"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <select x-model.number="promos.promo3.days">
      <option value="1">1 day</option>
      <option value="2">2 days</option>
      <option value="3">3 days</option>
    </select>

    <select x-model.number="promos.promo3.stars">
      <option value="1">1 star</option>
      <option value="2">2 stars</option>
      <option value="3">3 stars</option>
    </select>

    <div class="sum" x-text="promos.promo3.days * promos.promo3.stars"></div>
  </div>

  <div x-text="`Total: ${total}`"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% confident but, first, you have multiple id="sum" where it should be unique. It only gets the first element. Instead, you can use a class.

```
<div x-text="days * stars" class="sum"></div>
```

So it would give

```
$('.sum').each(function() {
    var value = parseInt($(this).text());
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      total += value;
    }
});
Alpine.store('total', total);
```

Everything together:

```
<div x-data="{ total: 0 }">
  <div class="flex" x-data="{ days: 1, stars: 1 }">
    <select x-model="days" @change="updateTotal()">
      <option value="1">1 day</option>
      <option value="2">2 days</option>
      <option value="3">3 days</option>
    </select>

    <select x-model="stars" @change="updateTotal()">
      <option value="1">1 star</option>
      <option value="2">2 stars</option>
      <option value="3">3 stars</option>
    </select>

    <div class="sum" x-text="days * stars"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex" x-data="{ days: 1, stars: 1 }">
    <select x-model="days" @change="updateTotal()">
      <option value="1">1 day</option>
      <option value="2">2 days</option>
      <option value="3">3 days</option>
    </select>

    <select x-model="stars" @change="updateTotal()">
      <option value="1">1 star</option>
      <option value="2">2 stars</option>
      <option value="3">3 stars</option>
    </select>

    <div class="sum" x-text="days * stars"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex" x-data="{ days: 1, stars: 1 }">
    <select x-model="days" @change="updateTotal()">
      <option value="1">1 day</option>
      <option value="2">2 days</option>
      <option value="3">3 days</option>
    </select>

    <select x-model="stars" @change="updateTotal()">
      <option value="1">1 star</option>
      <option value="2">2 stars</option>
      <option value="3">3 stars</option>
    </select>

    <div class="sum" x-text="days * stars"></div>
  </div>

  <div x-text="'Total: ' + total"></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function updateTotal() {
      var total = 0;
      $('.sum').each(function() {
        var value = parseInt($(this).text());
        if (!isNaN(value)) {
          total += value;
        }
      });
      Alpine.store('total', total);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      updateTotal();
    });

    Alpine.data('example', () => ({
      total: Alpine.store('total'),

      mounted() {
        this.$watch('$refs.sum', () => {
          updateTotal();
          this.total = Alpine.store('total');
        });
      },
    }));
  </script>
</div>
```